# How to replace google map marker icon with custom icon in @angular/google-maps module

Tags: angular, angular-material

component.html:

```
  <google-map (mapClick)="click($event)" 
  [center]="center" [options]="options" height="500px" width="100%"
    [zoom]="zoom">

    <map-marker (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker)" [clickable]="true"
  
    *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label"
      [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options">
    </map-marker>
    <map-info-window>Info Window content</map-info-window>
  </google-map>
```

component.ts:

```
options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 8,
  }
```

I've tried adding icon property with url value in options, passing input in map-marker but none worked

https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#readme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for **Angular Google Maps Marker** (https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps/map-marker) documentation, options includes all `map-marker` object properties that are not "*convenience inputs*":

> ...this component offers an options input as well as convenience
> inputs for position, title, label, and clickable, and supports all
> google.maps.Marker events as outputs.

so any other property that's not a "*convenience input*" has to be passed inside a JSON object like so to each marker object on your array:

```
      const markers =[
      {...},
      {...},
      [{
        position:{
           lat: 24.1  + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) / 100,
           lng: 0.2 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) / 100,
        },
        visible: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        label: {
           color: '#333',
           text: 'My Label',
        },
        title: 'My Title',
           options = {
           draggable: false, 
           icon: '../assets/icons/MyMarker.png'
        }
      }],
      {...},
      {...}
    ];
```

or, at least, it's what has to be inferred until documentation is completed.

Just past this code on your component and fill the ellipsis objects with needed data or just create an array with this structure from your own data.

Comment: Any other property not directly wrapped into the library can be sent to the Google Maps API inside the "options" object: animation, draggable,...

Answer (score 3):

A little digging into the node-modules of @angular/google-maps
I found out the icons should be set in the options of map marker.

```
 <map-marker (mapClick)="openInfoWindow(marker)" [clickable]="true"
  
    *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label"
      [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options">
    </map-marker>
```

for example the marker property should look like

```
     const markers = [{

        position:{
        lat: 27  + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) / 10,
        lng: 80 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) / 10,
      },
        visible: false,
        opacity: 0.1,
        label: {
          color: 'black',
          text: 'Marker label ',
        },
        title: 'Marker title ',
        options: {
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
        }
      }]
```